# Switching code around in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and have been experimenting with code I found online.  The following code is part of a script to find network info on a remote computer.

```
    $NETS = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName $First | Select DNSHostName, @{Name="IPAddress";Expression={$_.IPAddress[0]}}, 
    @{Name="IPSubnet";Expression={$_.IPSubnet[0]}}, @{Name="DefaultIPGateway";Expression={$_.DefaultIPGateway[0]}}, DHCPEnabled
```

It works fine, but I also want to get the serial number for the PC as well, so I use this

```
  $SN = Get-WMIObject win32_bios -ComputerName $First | Format-List SerialNumber
  $NETS | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SN -Value $SN.SerialNumber -Force
```

This works as well, but what I want is to flip them.  I want to get the serial number first and then append all the network info.  I have very little understanding of powershell though so I am unclear as to how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the SN in a calculated property as well:

```
$NETS = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName $First 
$NETS = $NETS |Select DNSHostName,
    @{Name='SN';Expression={ (Get-WMIObject win32_bios -ComputerName $First).SerialNumber}},
    @{Name="IPAddress";Expression={$_.IPAddress[0]}},
    @{Name="IPSubnet";Expression={$_.IPSubnet[0]}},
    @{Name="DefaultIPGateway";Expression={$_.DefaultIPGateway[0]}}, DHCPEnabled
```

Comment: This helps a lot with understanding powershell and works, thank you.  I was attempting something close to this, but I didn't think to try querying it right inside the property

Comment: Can be further optimized by getting rid of `$NETS=$NETS` and just continue the pipeline on the first command.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the answer @TheIncorrigible1 

Comment: I get the point, but I like to make things as simplified and verbose as possible  (like avoiding the use of aliases or repeated code where possible)